# How to create friendly URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, joomla

Please follow this URL (sample) http://www.test.com/test/vehicle?chrysler=crysler300  I want to change this URL http://www.test.com/test/vehicle/chrysler/crysler300 like this.
I try to do it using `.htaccess` file, but it not working.

This is the code I used

```
RewriteRule vehicle/chrysler/(.*) vehicle?chrysler=$1
```

Comment: mod_rewrite cannot change the URLs inside your PHP/HTML code.

Answer (score 6):

Your rewrite base is `test`.
So write something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^vehicle/chrysler/(.*) vehicle?chrysler=$1
```

also make sure you put your `.htaccess` file in document root. If you put it inside `test` directory, omit the `RewriteBase` directive.

Comment: RewriteBase /dimo/

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule vehicle/chrysler/(.*) vehicle?chrysler=$1

Comment: Add this code to your question please and comment about it, whether it's working or not

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^/test/vehicle/chrysler/(.*) http://www.test.com/test/vehicle?chrysler=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^vehicle/chrysler/?$ vehicle?chrysler=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`RewriteRule ^test/vehicle/chrysler/(.*) test/vehicle?chrysler=$1`

Check it on this site: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/